# Prolog problem: Variable and instanced variable do not unify, why? And how could I do it instead?

Tags: prolog, logic, gnu

Okay, hello everyone!

The problem domain for my Prolog problem is cryptographic protocols.

I've a Prolog program I'm trying to run in GNU Prolog. It should work...but of course it doesn't.

I'm trying to put the gist of it here:

```
% two people, c (the client) and a (the attacker)
% we have two public keys (asymmetric cryptographic keys, e.g.PGP)
publicKey(k_c).
publicKey(k_a).
% we have two private keys (asymmetric cryptographic keys, e.g.PGP)
privateKey(k_a-1).
privateKey(k_c-1).
% here I define the two public/private key pairs.
keyPair(k_c,k_c-1).
keyPair(k_a,k_a-1).
% just some kind of id
id(c).
id(a).
% nonces (some kind of value that's always new and is not guessable)
nonce(n_c).
nonce(n_a).
% two functions
% enc(Data, Key) encrypts Data with Key
cryptoFunction(enc(_,_)).
% sign(Data, Key) signs Data with Key (a signature)
cryptoFunction(sign(_,_)).

% a default message sent from the client to a server
init(n_c,k_c,sign([c,k_c],k_c-1)).

% Now I want to find out all combinations that can be sent without violating the rules
% The server always checks for some kind of guard (see below)

% define the message template
init(Init_1, Init_2, Init_3) :-
% define the types
nonce(Init_1),
publicKey(Init_2),
id(Init_3_1_1),
% example:
% Init_3_1_2 means init
% third parameter of init (the sign function)
% first parameter of sign function
% second part of the concatenation
publicKey(Init_3_1_2),
privateKey(Init_3_2),
% build the message
Init_3 = sign(Init_3_1,Init_3_2),
Init_3_1 = [Init_3_1_1,Init_3_1_2],
keyPair(Init_2,SignKey).
Init_3 == sign([_,Init_2],SignKey).
```

The last rule of the body, "Init_3 == sign([_,Init_2],SignKey)" is the guard that the server is checking.

Now when I trace with Prolog, the last part is instantiated to

```
sign([c,k_c],k_c-1) == sign([_281,k_c],k_c-1)
```

And then fails. Why doesn't _281 instantiate to c? Everything else is okay. Do I have to use Init_3_1_1 as the variable name? Or is there another way to be able to use the guard?

I hope I explained the problem well, if not, please do tell.

Comment: Damn, I had tried the unification before using equality, but the trace seemed to always loop around using different private keys. It never showed "Trying to fulfill the last rule" in the trace...but it seems it is only shown if the rule is true... I mean the trace doesn't show "FAIL: Guard Rule".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unification is the built-in predicate (=)/2, not (==)/2. Example:

```
?- sign([c,k_c],k_c-1) = sign([_281,k_c],k_c-1).
_281 = c.
```